# socket.io with express

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

i have a project and I'm using socket.io with express ,

so what i need (i tried) is broadcasting a message but from an express action.
is this possible i don't know how to get a reference to send or broadcast.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
//i need to send messages from here 
});
```

Other things like using both express+socket.io is working with me :)

Answer (score 4):

As long as I understand,

Why not use the socket message type as an event instead of a http get or post? On the client side you would send a message via the websocket with let's say an event property.

So in your case:

```
<script>
  // Initialize socket.io ...

  // and then
  socket.send({event: 'homepage loaded', foo: 'bar'});
</script>
```

And on the server side:

```
var io = io.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (client) {
  client.on('message', function (message) {
    if (message.event == 'homepage loaded') {
      client.broadcast(...);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to have a look at my [socket.io + Express primer](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/). What you want is covered in detail there.

```
// Send to all connected sockets
io.sockets.send('Hello, World!');

// Send to all sockets in a specified room
io.sockets.in('room').send('Hello, Room!');
```

Where `io` is the value returned by the call to `socketio.listen()`. You can place that code anywhere in your application, eg in your `app.get` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my example repo where I use ExpressJS + Juggernaut(pubsub over socket.io):

http://github.com/shripadk/express-juggernaut-demo

This might be overkill for what you need as it uses Publish/Subscribe. But it does, to a certain extent, solve your issue of using regular ExpressJS routes. Checkout the master branch after cloning the repository:

`git checkout master`

Comment: When i execute "git clone git://github.com/shripadk/express-juggernaut.git" i get this error:"fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Comment: Do you mean executing this command "git clone git://github.com/shripadk/express-juggernaut-demo.git",this is work for me but when i make "git checkout master" i get "Already on 'master'
", i ignored this and run the demo put i get this

Comment: The 'sys' module is now called 'util'. It should have a similar interface.
node.js:50
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'utils'
    at resolveModuleFilename (node.js:265:13)
    at loadModule (node.js:231:20)
    at require (node.js:291:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ibrahim/ws/Lebanon/staTest/express-juggernaut-demo/lib/support/juggernaut/lib/juggernaut/channel.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (node.js:348:23)
    at Object..js (node.js:356:12)
    at Module.load (node.js:279:25)

Comment: at loadModule (node.js:251:12)
    at require (node.js:291:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ibrahim/ws/Lebanon/staTest/express-juggernaut-demo/lib/support/juggernaut/lib/juggernaut/publish.js:4:15)

Comment: Use node v0.2.4! I guess you are on node v0.3.0! you need to wait till all modules work with v0.3.0 to use that version. :)

Comment: I installed node v0.2.4 and reinstalled all the required modules but node-static,it need V0.3 ,i ignored this so now i have node-static for the v0.3.i start redis but i get this :/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis-client/0.3.5/package/lib/redis-client.js:394
    var callback = originalCommand[originalCommand.length - 1];

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Client.onReply_ (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis-client/0.3.5/package/lib/redis-client.js:394:51)
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis-client/0.3.5/package/lib/redis-client.js:136:34
    at ReplyParser.feed (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis-client/0.3.5/package/lib/redis-client.js:169:21)
    at Stream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis-client/0.3.5/package/lib/redis-client.js:337:28)
    at Stream.emit (events:27:15)
    at IOWatcher.callback (net:489:16)
    at node.js:772:9
Could this be related to the node-static module ?

Comment: and make sure that you have the right version of redis-client: `npm install redis-client@0.3.5`

Comment: Thanks man im learning new things from you,but i still have this " /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis-client/0.3.5/package/lib/redis-client.js:394
    var callback = originalCommand[originalCommand.length - 1];
                                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
"

Comment: I tried all nodejs versions and uninstalled all the npm module but still have the same problem. I Found a nice example how to make what i need but with faye it's here http://nodecasts.org/ .Thanks very much Shrippad K

Comment: no don't accept if it did not help you. Against the stackoverflow community rules :)

Answer (score 0):

I Found a nice example how to make what i need but with faye it's here http://nodecasts.org/.

I don't know the difference between Juggernaut ,Faye and direct Socket.io but Faye is good

for my case .And i think both of them use Socket.io internally.

Comment: Faye doesn't use socket.io internally. It is based on bayeux protocol. However, it is good :)