# Get a static request to push some data to clients using Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm new to Node.js, and I've been playing with the "chat" example provided with the [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) install package. Is shows in a few lines of code how you can push some data to several clients (browsers) in a push-fashion (no pulling).

Here is the code on the server side : http://pastie.org/1537175

I get how you can send a message to a client with client.broadcast(msg), but I don't get how  you can do it outside of the

> io.on('connection', function(client){
>   ... }

loop

I would like to invoke a client.broadcast(msg) when someone hits a particular url (like '/test.html'), see line #32. The device asking for the '/test.html' is not a typical "ajax-enabled" browser, but a mere text-based browser, so I cannot initialize an asynchronous request with the server. Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .broadcast on your io object

```
case '/test.html':
    io.broadcast('test'); // This is where I would like to invoke a client.broadcast(msg);
    break;
```

Comment: Thx, i feel so stupid! I ended up using express + faye : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096946/socket-io-with-express